# C++, why can you pass rvalue to a function which takes lvalue reference as argument

Tags: c++

Why is is that you can pass an rvalue to a function which requires a reference?

```
void func(const std::string& x)
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::string& x = "Test"; //fails to compile
    func("Test"); //works
    return 0;
}
```

Before trying it I thought I would need to create a string variable before calling func.

```
std::string tmp = "Test";
func(tmp);
```

Much like I would need to in order to create a reference.

```
std::string tmp = "Test";
std::string& x = tmp;
```

Comment: I can't get what you mean. `std::string&` and `const std::string&` are not the same things.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not about passing to a function, it's about the `lvalue` reference being to a `const` object.

```
std::string& x = "Test"; //fails to compile
```

The above attempts to bind a temporary to a non-const reference. If we were to tweak it, it would be well formed:

```
std::string const& x = "Test"; // compiles
```

Now it extends the lifetime of the temporary until the reference goes out of scope, as mandated by the c++ standard.
Knowing this, we can make your function fail to compile as well by changing the prototype to:

```
void func(std::string& x)
```

Now the functions parameter can't bind to temporary objects, since it accepts by a non-const reference.

---

For the post c++11 age, things are a bit more interesting. You can bind temporaries to non-const `rvalue` references:

```
std::string&& x = "Test"; //Okay and still extends the lifetime of the temporary
```