# Saving references

Tags: c++, reference

Consider the following uncomplicated code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

template<class It, class Fun>
void parallel_for(size_t num_threads, It first, It end, const Fun& fun) {
    std::queue<std::thread> ts;
    for (It it = first; it != end; ++it) {
        if (std::distance(first, it) % num_threads == 0) {
            fun(*it);
        } else {
            if (ts.size() == num_threads-1) {
                ts.front().join();
                ts.pop();
            }
            ts.push(std::thread(fun, std::ref(*it)));
        }
    }
    while (not ts.empty()) {
        ts.front().join();
        ts.pop();
    }
}

int main() {
    std::atomic_int counter = 1;
    auto lam = [&counter](auto& vl) {
                vl = std::pair(counter++, -1);
            };

    // The following usage of std::ref works okay:
    pair<int, int> x;
    auto blam = bind(lam, ref(x));
    blam();
    
    // Nevertheless, the next line fails:
    // lam(ref(x));
    
    // As well as the next two ones:
    // vector<pair<int, int>> v = {{4, 2}};
    // parallel_for(thread::hardware_concurrency(), begin(v), end(v), lam);
    
    return 0;
}
```

GCC's error on the last two lines, in particular, is

```
In file included from ./src/csc_cpp/passing_lambdas.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/10/thread: In instantiation of ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = const main()::<lambda(auto:1&)>&; _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<std::pair<int, int> >}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]’:
./src/csc_cpp/passing_lambdas.cpp:22:26:   required from ‘void parallel_for(size_t, It, It, const Fun&) [with It = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<int, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > >; Fun = main()::<lambda(auto:1&)>; size_t = long unsigned int]’
./src/csc_cpp/passing_lambdas.cpp:47:71:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/10/thread:136:44: error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
  136 |           typename decay<_Args>::type...>::value,
      |                                            ^~~~~
```

I am sure this is a trivial matter, but I am anyway struggling to understand this. I think I have been following the available examples on `std::thread::thread()`'s intended use quite closely, but this does not compile. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++, why can you pass rvalue to a function which takes lvalue reference as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41322023/c-why-can-you-pass-rvalue-to-a-function-which-takes-lvalue-reference-as-argum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me clarify, because I'm not sure if it's obvious: the trick behind [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) is that it returns an object of type [`std::reference_wrapper<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper), so you can use the result as object, but the object is implicitly convertible to `T&`, so it can be substituted where `T&` is needed.

---

`lam(ref(x));` fails because you use `auto` in `lam`. Compiler doesn't know that you want `vl` to be `std::pair<int, int>&`, it deduces from what it gets. `std::ref` returns a temporary of `std::reference_wrapper<std::pair<int, int>>`, which cannot be bound to non-`const` reference. Use explicit type in lambda and it compiles:

```
    auto lam = [&counter](std::pair<int, int>& vl) {
                vl = std::pair(counter++, -1);
            };
    lam(std::ref(x));
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly convert to `std::pair<int, int>&` using `get()` or `static_cast`

```
auto lam = [&counter](auto& vl) {
            vl = std::pair(counter++, -1);
        };
lam(std::ref(x).get());
lam(static_cast<std::pair<int, int>&>(std::ref(x)));
```

---

The second part with `parallel_for` has exactly the same issue, you pass rvalue of `std::reference_wrapper` to `lam`.

Answer (score 0):

About

```
lam(ref(x));
```

`x` is an `lvalue` while the `ref(x)` is a temporary `reference_wrapper`. You can not grab a temporary with an lvalue reference in your `lam` through `auto&`.

for that line, you can simply use

```
lam(x);
```